# backbone (underscore) template issue

Tags: templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm having a little bit weird issue with backbone template.

I have the following template

```
    <div class='content'>
        <img src="assets/images/room/temp-img.jpg" class='room-image'/>
        <div class="room-content-right">
            <h2 class='room-name'><%= title %> </h2>
            <p class="room-description"><%= shortDescription %></p>     

            <a class='btn-view-detail'><%= dictionary.viewDetail %></a>     

            <div class='float-right'>
                <div class='text-startingAt'><%= dictionary.startingAt %> $xxx / <%= dictionary.night %></div>
                <a class="btn-select-room"><%= dictionary.selectThisRoom %></a>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="clear-both"></div>


    </div>

    <ul class='packages'>

    </ul>
```

When I render it, I get the following HTML

[image]

As you see, VIEW DETAIL anchor is out of its place with div.float-right.

Am I doing something wrong or is this bug from backbone?

Comment: Oh. How did you do it? :) I don't think it's a bug. So could you post the relevant code snippet?

Comment: You're doing something that produces invalid HTML and the browser is rearranging things to get valid HTML. Notice the `<p></p>` above `.btn-view-detail`? That's a give away that the browser is trying to fix your broken HTML. What are all the values that you're putting in the template?

Comment: @Moon you template is wrong. Did you notice the anchor is indeed out of it's place in template too?

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm checking tags one by one..will be back with result..

Comment: @muistooshort // you're right. the content of <%= shortDescription %> was causing this issue. <%= shortDescription %> contains a broken div tag.

Comment: That sounds about right. I was trying to reproduce your problem by throwing various bits of broken HTML into the variables but gave up before I got to that one. Oh well, that'll teach you to validate all your HTML before putting it in your database :)